# JSFtp throwing unhandled error

Tags: node.js, ftp

I have a JSFtp implementation which is used for FTP putting files to a server. My problem is whenever the given host data to the JSFtp() is wrong it gives an unhandled error from the

```
jsftp({host:...});
```

which causes the process to exit prematurely. Can anyone tell me any method to overcome this as try...catch doesn't work with this?

Answer (score 1):

Handle the error with the 'error' event:

```
var ftp = new jsftp({
    host: 'badhost',
    user: 'user',
    port: 21,
    pass: '12345'
});

ftp.on('error', function(err) {
    // Handle error
});
```